# Poor React Native debugging experience

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I've seen quite a few posts about debugging issues of React Native apps, though none of them is quite the same issue that I'm having.

The issue is that I place `debugger`'s in my code wherever I need to inspect something and even though I hit the break points that I place, JS Console in Chrome never shows me where I put the `debugger` and because of that I can never inspect the values properly.

Just to give you an example, I may have something like this:

```
...
const myVar = someFunction();
debugger;
```

When I run the code, it will pause execution somewhere in my code but never where the `debugger` is. And if I were to inspect the value of `myVar`, it always shows `undefined`.

I'm using `VS Code` on `Windows 10` against the emulator that comes with `Android Studio`. Also, the remote debug is running on `Chrome`. I also want to mention that all of the software I mentioned here, including the OS, are completely up-to-date.

Is debugging a React Native app always a poor experience -- based on so many complaints I'm seeing?

Is it also a poor experience on a Mac?

Though I don't think this is the issue, could it be the tools I'm using? I think `VS Code`, `Chrome` and `Android Studio` are pretty much what most people use -- whether they're on a PC or a Mac.

Any idea how I can have a decent experience in debugging my React Native apps?